Is "Thank you" means "Yes" here?
Here is the conversation between Nettie and Reta in Killers Of The Flower Moon (2023):

Reta: Nettie?
Nettie: Yes.
Reta: Can you get my sister some toast, please?
Nettie: Of course. And a bit more coffee too?
Reta: Thank you.

Is "Thank you" means "Yes" here?

It 'means' 'yes please, and thank you for being extra helpful by offering to do more than I asked'.

Does "Thank you" mean "Yes" here? My mother used to correct me for saying "Thank you" in situations like that - she said it could be understood as "No, thank you" and I should say "Yes, please".

@KateBunting - So did mine!

@KateBunting Really?! While my lawful-neutral alignment can sympathize with the urge to follow the designated script, I have a hard time imagining "thank you" being effectively used as a negative without any negative word added.

@AndyBonner - Well, that was Mum's idea. I don't necessarily agree, especially as I would have said it in a 'positive' tone of voice (if you know what I mean).

@AndyBonner Irrelevant here but in French, when someone offer something, replying merci (thank you) alone always imply a refusal.

@jlliagre - bah ouais !

@MichaelHarvey And if someone offer not to give something, whether you reply oui or non doesn't matter. You agree not to get it in both cases.

@jlliagre - can't you say mais si ! ....?

@MichaelHarvey Yes, that's the way to do it. Si and oui are not interchangeable. This reply states English used to make the same distinction with yes/yea.

@jlliagre - Yes, the answers to positively framed questions ("Will he go?") were yea and nay, whilst the answers to negatively framed questions ("Will he not go?") were yes and no. In the Middle Ages.

OP's query is regarding a  conversation in a movie

Reta: Nettie?
Nettie: Yes.
Reta: Can you get my sister some toast, please?
Nettie: Of course. And a bit more coffee too?
Reta: Thank you.
Is "Thank you" means "Yes" here?

Normally the response "Thank you" when you are offered something means, "No, thank you for asking.".
But in this case, Reta had asked for some toast for her sister.
Nettie's offer of more coffee is in continuation with that request.
So here without stating, "No" Nettie would comprehend  that Rita's"Thank you "  actually means "Yes, please bring more coffee, too."

"Thank you" doesn't directly mean "yes" but in certain contexts, like your example, it can imply agreement or acceptance in a way that functions similarly to "yes". I'd say this is more a matter of etiquette than grammar, but gratitude can be used to confirm or accept an offer or a suggestion.
Having said that, your example reads a little like a script, so it doesn't account for body language - maybe Reta held out her coffee cup to signal that she wanted more. A gesture, or even a nod or a smile could have sent the message that meant "yes".
